# Firebase .push() attempting to add to DB, but fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a component that checks to see if a user has upvoted a post before.  If they have then they can't upvote that post again.  If they haven't then they are allowed to.

The code works great for the first user to be added.  Firebase creates a unique key and then adds `upVotedBy: userKey`.  However if I try to log in as another user and do the same thing it will not add the record for the new user. It's also not logging any sort of error.

If I look at Firebase while upVoting it attempts to add the new record with a unique key and then turns red and retracts it.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I've narrowed it down and it appears that if there is already a record, any record, it won't add it. It will add the first one, but won't add any subsequent records.

My data is structured like this:

[image: Data Structure]

Here is the component:

```
handleUpVote: function(item){
    var ref = new Firebase(rootUrl);
    var authData = ref.getAuth();
    if(authData){
      var userKey = authData.uid;
      console.log('this is userKey ' + userKey)
      var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, item);
      ref.child('items').child(this.props.keyNum).child('upVotedBy').once('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
          console.log('this is snapshot.key ' + childSnapshot.val().upVotedBy);
          if(childSnapshot.val().upVotedBy === userKey){
            this.setState({userUpvoted: true})
            console.log('u already liked this')
          }
        }.bind(this))
      }.bind(this)).then(function(){
        if(this.state.userUpvoted === false){
          console.log('okay u can like this')
          stateCopy.upVotes += 1;
          ref.child('items').child(this.props.keyNum).child('upVotedBy').push({
            upVotedBy: userKey
          }, function(error){
            if(error){
              console.log('push error: ' + error)
            }
          })
          console.log(stateCopy.upVotedBy)
          this.fb.update(stateCopy);
        }
      }.bind(this))

    } else {
      console.log('must be logged in to upvote')
    }


},
```

Comment: Can you show how the data looks in firebase? I can't really tell how you you have structured the data from this code alone.

Comment: @AndréKool Sure thing. added

Comment: So a user just loops through all items and checks if he has already upvoted that item? And your problem is when for example user a has already upvoted the item user b can't upvote it? Sorry if i ask to much, i haven't had enough coffee yet :P

Comment: No worries! Well the looping and everything works fine.  The issue is that Firebase won't add more than one record to upper most `upVotedBy`.  It works for only one user.  If I were to delete test and then go in as User A and upvote a post, it would add everything correctly.  If I were to try and re-upvote that post as User A, everything would work correctly.  If I were to log out and log in as User B, Firebase won't add another record.  For some reason it's like it's only allowing one record.

Answer (score 2):

Got some coffee and the answer :) For more explenation or questions just comment.

The problem is in the way you save an upvote. My suggesting is to do it like this:

```
-Items
   -itemid1
      -upvotedBy
         -userA: true
         -userB: true
   -itemid2
      -upvotedBy
         -userA: false
         -userB: true
```

And in you check you would have to do something like this:

```
ref.child('items').child(this.props.keyNum).child('upVotedBy').once('value', function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
      if(childSnapshot.key() === userKey){
        //see if it is upvoted using childSnapshot.val()
      }
    }.bind(this))
  }
```

And for saving an upvote you have to use set() instead of push()

```
ref.child('items').child(this.props.keyNum).child('upVotedBy').child(userKey).set(true);
```

Comment: Storing the users who voted as a key, looks like the right approach indeed. Although I'd probably only store the users that have `true`. What is the `setState()` method that you're calling btw?

Comment: I copied setState() from the question. I hope i did it right.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. :-)

Comment: @AndréKool Sorry for the delayed response.  You may want to revise your `set()` method to not use object literal notation.  I need to declare the new object first and then use `set(newObj)` so that I can store the variable as the key.  However now it seems to be trying to add the database twice.  Also, the `stateCopy` thing I was using to set the upVotes was causing havoc and trying to save the data twice.  I got it working. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i updated my answer :) And nice you fixed the problem.